# Fortran Unit Testing with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, fortran

**Dear all**,

I tried to find any existing documentation about Fortran and **Unit testing** in Visual Studio but couldn't find any.
Do you have experience with Unit Testing for Fortran, can you recommend some good tutorials or books for that topic? The tools need to integrate into the Visual Studio 19 environment and I would love to use the built in Test-Explorer. (I use the Intel Compiler, but that should not matter for testing, right?)

best regards,

Answer (score 1):

There are several Fortran unit testing tools out there:
http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Unit+testing+frameworks
I guess you should check them first.

Comment: "The tools need to integrate into the Visual Studio 19 environment and I would love to use the built in Test-Explorer."

Answer (score 0):

#### Fortran Unit Test Library FUT

dongli created this easy applicable library for Fortran unit testing:

https://github.com/dongli/fortran-unit-test

The following sample shows the usage of this library:

```
program good_test

  use unit_test

  implicit none

  type(test_suite_type)  specific_suite

  ! example with default suite
  call test_case_init()

  call test_case_create('Test 1')

  ! By sending macros __FILE__ and __LINE__, report will print the file and line number where assertion fails.
  call assert_approximate(1.0, 2.0, __FILE__, __LINE__) ! line 14

  call test_suite_report()
  call test_case_final()

  ! example with specific suite
  specific_suite%name = 'my specific test suite'
  call test_case_create('Specific Test 1', specific_suite)
  ! suite = SUITE need in this case (cause optional argument eps, file_name, line_number is missing)
  call assert_approximate(1.0, 2.0, suite=specific_suite)

  call test_case_create('Specific Test 2', specific_suite)
  ! suite = SUITE need in this case (cause optional argument eps is missing)
  call assert_equal(1.0, 2.0, __FILE__, __LINE__,  suite=specific_suite)

  call test_case_create('Specific Test 3', specific_suite)
  call assert_approximate(1.0, 2.0, __FILE__, __LINE__, 1E-0, specific_suite)

  ! report a test_case
  call test_case_report('Specific Test 2', specific_suite)

  ! report the complete suite
  call test_suite_report(specific_suite)
  call test_case_final(specific_suite)

end program good_test
```

The output looks like:

```
///////////////////// Report of Suite: Default test suite ///////////////////////

 +-> Details:
 |   |
 |   +-> Test 1: 1 of 1 assertions succeed.
 |   |
 |
 +-> Summary:
 |   +-> Default test suite: 1 of 1 assertions succeed.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////// Report of Suite: my specific test suite, Case: Specific Test 2 /////////

 +-> Specific Test 2: 0 of 1 assertions succeed.
 |   |
 |   +-> Assertion #1 failed with reason: x ( 1.000) == y ( 2.000)
 |   +-> Check line: test_assert.F90:29

/////////////////// Report of Suite: my specific test suite /////////////////////

 +-> Details:
 |   |
 |   +-> Specific Test 1: 1 of 1 assertions succeed.
 |   |
 |   +-> Specific Test 2: 0 of 1 assertions succeed.
 |   |   |
 |   |   +-> Assertion #1 failed with reason: x ( 1.000) == y ( 2.000)
 |   |   +-> Check line: test_assert.F90:29
 |   |
 |   +-> Specific Test 3: 0 of 1 assertions succeed.
 |   |   |
 |   |   +-> Assertion #1 failed with reason: x ( 1.000) =~ y ( 2.000)
 |   |   +-> Check line: test_assert.F90:32
 |   |
 |
 +-> Summary:
 |   +-> my specific test suite: 1 of 3 assertions succeed.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: "The tools need to integrate into the Visual Studio 19 environment and I would love to use the built in Test-Explorer."

Comment: @CTZStef: As it's available on GitHub, try to contact the developer [dongli](https://github.com/dongli), if he is interested in writing a Visual Studio extension for this or try to do it yourself. Otherwise feel free to upvote my answer if you find it helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I do not find your answer useful as a matter of fact, since the question specifically mentioned Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Honestly I'm developing software with Intel Fortran and Visual Studio 2019 using this unit test suite. It fits completely to my needs (console applications, number crunchers). It needs of course some configuration at the beginning, but it's the best what I've found so far for Visual Studio and Fortran software development.

Comment: oh, I see. Well then I would say - and that's just the opinion of someone who did not spend too much time looking into this yet - what's missing is *how* can we integrate this unit test framework within VS2019. I am using Intel Fortran as well, and I would be very interested to know how you did it.